# Encapsulated styles for a story in Angular Storybook

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

**Question**
How can I have specific scss files loaded for individual stories?

**Details**
I am using Storybook 7 with Angular 17 to document a component library. There's 1 global stylesheet with a couple components that are styled slightly differently based on the brand. For consuming applications, those differences are handled via a couple different imports based on the brand. However, I cannot do this in Storybook because all the styles are global – the small differences in styles would both be loaded, thereby conflicting.

One way I have tried managing this is by creating "wrapper" components and using Angular's ViewEncapsulation to capture those style differences

These components are at the path: `stories/typography/wrapper/`, whereas most of the other styles are in a base global `styles` directory.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";


/**
 * This component is needed so we can load the different styles
 * for the different themes as needed
 */
@Component({
    selector: "typography-wrapper",
    styleUrls: ["./typography-wrapper.styles.scss"],
    template:`<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class TypographyWrapper {}

@Component({
    selector: "typography-v2-wrapper",
    styleUrls: ["./typography-v2-wrapper.styles.scss"],
    template:`<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class TypographyV2Wrapper {}
```

And the styles:

```scss
// "./typography-v2-wrapper.styles.scss"

@import "styles/brand2/variables";
@import "styles/brand2/mixins";
@import "styles/brand2/components/type";
```

```scss
// "./typography-wrapper.styles.scss"

@import "styles/brand1/variables";
@import "styles/brand1/mixins";
@import "styles/brand1/components/type";
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class at the root component that will determine which style sheet group to use. In your app.component.ts you could add the class that determines which style to use!

You need `renderer2` for adding the body class.

```
 ....
 constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2) {}
 ...
 ngOnInit() {
    const brandClass = isBrand1 ? 'brand1-styles' : 'brand2-styles';
    this.renderer2.addClass(document.body.parentElement, brandClass);
    this.renderer2.addClass(document.body, brandClass );
 }
 ....
```

and your stylesheet can be defined as

/ "./typography-v2-wrapper.styles.scss"

```
.brand2-styles {
    @import "styles/brand2/variables";
    @import "styles/brand2/mixins";
    @import "styles/brand2/components/type";
    // "./typography-wrapper.styles.scss"
}

.brand1-styles {
    @import "styles/brand1/variables";
    @import "styles/brand1/mixins";
    @import "styles/brand1/components/type";
}
```

Note: `@import` might be deprecated in future so go for `@use` which is going to be the replacement for it!